# Disable Autocorrect for a certain style sheet

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, autocorrect

Is it possible to disable auto correct (such as fixing capitalization) for a specific style template only? I'm interested in a solution for Word 2013.

This is specifically for auto correct, configured `File / Options / Document proofing (?) / Auto Correct`.

The purpose is to disable it for the style sheet used for code samples. Auto correct from `int` to `Int` is painful, but I don't want to lose auto correct completely.

Comment: I would like this for the exact same use.

Answer (score 5):

MsWord - > In the Styles group on the Home Tab (Expand it)->Apply Style ->(Selected style is to be Normal) modify (do required modification)->Format->Language -> uncheck the spell check(if thats also not required)

for specific style you can check this link

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/acoat/turning-off-proofing-and-autocorrect-in-word-2007)

Comment: This is already enabled, but turns off spell checking only (squiggly lines). However, auto correction (as configured in file / Options / Document proofing (?) / Auto Correct) is still active, e.g. changing capitalization and the beginning of a paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's possible with templates, but you could use a macro for disabling the autocorrection features which you don't want on launch of the file and re-enable them on close.

Something in the direction like this:

```
Application.AutoCorrect.TwoInitialCapitals = False
```

or a little bit more general

```
Application.AutoCorrect.ReplaceText = False
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Modify style`
2. At the bottom of the page, choose `paragraph` section for style editing
3. Goto second tab `Line and Page Breaks`
4. Check `formatting exceptions`: `Suppress line numbers` and `Don't hyphenate`

Certified and works on Mac MS-Word version 16.x

Comment: Does not work for me on Windows MS Word 2016.

Answer (score -1):

For disabling autocorrect option 
MSword -> file->option ->proofing

You will options to disable it.Also from 'autocorrect option' inside proofing.

Comment: That’s explicitly *not* what @peterchen asked for. He wants to turn it off *only* for a particular style, not for everything in the program.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to your Charms Bar (press <kbd>Window</kbd>s + <kbd>C</kbd>).
2. Click Settings.
3. Click Change PC Settings (located at the bottom of the Settings column).
4. Click General.
5. Go to the Spelling section.
6. Turn off “Autocorrect Misspelled Words” option.

To close this app, move your cursor to the top of the page until it becomes a hand icon now click and drag off the screen.

Comment: This disables AutoCorrect completely, not just for selected style sheets.