# Prevent Microsoft Word 2010 auto-completing company name?

Tags: microsoft-word, autocomplete

The name of my company is very similar to a normal word I type regularly (e.g. my company is *SuperShop Ltd.* and I regularly type "*super*"). Microsoft Word 2010 tries to be helpful and offers to auto-complete the company name if I press the Enter key.

At best this is distracting, but at worst it's problematic, as I can accidentally include my company name in bulleted lists (or any other place where pressing the Enter key is likely).

I can't see any way to disable this in the Proofing options. Am I missing something? I suppose a work-around would be to [remove the company name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290528) from the Office 2010 system, but that would be unfortunate.

Answer (score 3):

I can see this is an old question, but I had a user with this problem (our company name starts with 'London' which is where we're based so it's often written in addresses) and thought I'd share the solution I found. This is for Word 2013 but I assume it would work in 2010 too.

The cause is not an autocorrect but QuickPart AutoText. In Word, select the Insert Tab, Quick Parts and under AutoText you will see your name, initials and company name. To remove these, select Building Blocks Organiser under the Quick Parts menu and select each in turn and Delete.

Comment: Glad to see you jumping in to help. It is OK to answer an old question, especially if it doesn't have an accepted answer. Good job.

Answer (score 1):

From [this tutorial](http://www.sean.co.uk/books/microsoft-office-2010-2007-older-wiser/office-turn-off-predictive-text.shtm):

> 1 - Click the **File** tab in the top left.
>  2 - Click **Options**
>   on the left. It's in smaller text, just above the red Exit button.
>   3 - In the new window that opens, click **Proofing**, on the left.
>   4 - Click **AutoCorrect Options**, near the top of the right panel of
>   that window. A new window will open.
>  5 - Untick the box beside
>   **Replace text as you type**. You can also untick options for changing two initial capitals to be just one, capitalising the first letter of
>   sentences, capitalising names of days and capitalising the first
>   letter of table cells.
>  6 - Click **OK** in the bottom right
>   AutoCorrect window. You should see two OK buttons on screen, and you
>   have to click the one on the smaller window first.
>  7 - Click
>   **OK** in the bottom right of the options menu.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm only interested in preventing one particular auto-correction. I don't want to disable the entire functionality.

Comment: @DuncanJones There should be a list of text that is automatically replaced by Word, you can delete the text corresponding to your company's name from that list so that Word doesn't automatically replace it.

Comment: Nope, sorry. The company name is obviously a special case for Word - it's not listed in the collection of editable auto-correct options.

Comment: @DuncanJones Have you tried disabling the spellcheck for the style of your company name's formatting? Take a look at Sjk's second answer to [this question:](http://superuser.com/questions/547777/disable-autocorrect-for-a-certain-style-sheet) `MsWord - > In the Styles group on the Home Tab (Expand it)->Apply Style ->(Selected style is to be Normal) modify (do required modification)->Format->Language -> uncheck the spell check(if thats also not required)`

Comment: Assuming [this](http://superuser.com/a/547825/200425) is the answer you're referring to, then no - this cannot be solved using styles.

Comment: Can't check as I'm not sure how to replicate your situation, but I wonder if either of the following would help: (1) set up the word you want to type as an autocorrect entry and set the corrected version to be the same word (Might override what Word is doing). (2) set up your own short autocorrect for this particular word. But then you'd have to remember to use it!

Comment: @bibadia Thanks for the ideas. Sadly neither of those worked. The auto-completion of the company name seems to supersede all other auto-correct settings. Perhaps this behaviour is unavoidable.

Comment: @DuncanJones - a pity. FWIW I wasn't sure which company string you meant - if it's the one that appears in the Document Properties->Advanced Properties->Summary, then I don't see the behaviour here. I'm wondering whether what you are seeing is actually a result of a SmartTag (you can have a look in the AutoCorrect dialog box, Actions tab and see what's enabled. If you experimentally disable things in there, you'll probably have to restart all Office programs. Out of ideas after that.