# Is there a way to have MS Word not autocorrect in selected document regions?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, autocorrect

I'm setting up some tables where some cells will contain either a single lowercase letter or two lowercase letters. (Specifically, I'm trying to set up Punnett squares from genetics.) So, e.g., a cell should contain "a" or "aa." When I edit the cell and then leave it by tabbing away or clicking out, autocorrect treats it as the start of a sentence and capitalizes it: "A" or "Aa." What I'd like to be able to do is somehow tell Word to *not* autocorrect just in that table, while leaving autocorrect on for the rest of the document.

I've tried turning on "Do not check spelling or grammar" (in the language dialog) for the text, as suggested in https://superuser.com/a/547825 and  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/acoat/2009/08/08/turning-off-proofing-and-autocorrect-in-word-2007/, but that didn't work. I tried using both a style change and direct formatting, but Word still autocorrected the text (both in a table and in regular body text).

If it matters, I'm using Word 2010; but I'd prefer a solution that will also work on newer versions (and preferably on OSX versions of Word, as well). A VBA solution is acceptable but not ideal.

Comment: You can use File | Options | Proofing | AutoCorrect Options | Capitalize first letter of table cells uncheck it

Comment: See https://superuser.com/a/836247/213131

Comment: @Twisty Thanks! I'll try that today and see how it works for me. It's similar to what I'd already tried, but I'd applied the setting using direct formatting, not as part of a style.